# Unable to find module for DevMenu - after upgrading to Expo 44

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I'm going crazy - when I launch the app on a real device, I'm getting `Unable to find module for DevMenu` and the whole app is frozen on the splashscreen. I have seen [this](https://forums.expo.dev/t/unable-to-find-module-for-devmenu/34024/5) which alludes that if I turn off remote debugging, it could fix it, but the app is completely unresponsive, so when I shake it, the Expo options don't show up.

When I launch it on a simulator, I see the error, but it's not fatal. Again, I can not seem to open the Expo menu anymore on the simulator to test if it is the remote debugger causing the issue. But the app runs fine on the simulator, other than that.

What is the error `Unable to find module for DevMenu` and how can I fix it?

Real device:
[image]

Simulator logs:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. What solved it was to install expo-dev-menu :

```
npm i expo-dev-menu
```

And importing it in my App.js.

```
import 'expo-dev-menu';
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: after adding I'm getting errors like Project with path ':expo-manifests' could not be found in the project ':expo-dev-menu'.